# How to define global variable with different values in python

Tags: python

I would like to know how to call one global variable with two different values in a class and call them in the other class (within which behave such as flags).

in SerialP.py

```
Class SerialP(object):
    def ReceiveFrame (self, data, length):
        global myvariable

        if x:
            myvariable = 1:
        elif y:
            myvariable = 2
```

in fmMain.py

```
Class fmMain:
    def OnReadConfig(self, event):
        if SerialP.myvariable = 1:
            #do this task
        if SerialP.myvariable = 2:
            #do another task
```

Comment: Equality check is with `==`, not with `=`. Apart from that (and messy indentation), your code looks okay. What problems are you experiencing? Of course you need to call that method to create the variable first...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How to make a local variable (inside a function) global](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051916/python-how-to-make-a-local-variable-inside-a-function-global)

Comment: The indentation of your code is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code.
First, comparison is done with `==` and not with `=` which is used for assignment. Also, you have not included the `import` statement which might be misleading.

In  fmMain.py

```
import SerialP  # and not from SerialP import SerialP

Class fmMain:
    def OnReadConfig(self, event):
      if SerialP.myvariable == 1:  # changed to ==
          #do this task
      if SerialP.myvariable == 2:  # changed to ==
          #do another task
```