# Is there a way to make the list change without a return in the function? (Sort function)

Tags: python, function

In my code,

Bubble sort, insertion sort, and quick sort are implemented
and the first two are printed without any problems running as mains.
But the last quick sort doesn't reflect the sorted list.

```py
def Quick(item, reverse):

    if reverse:
        if len(item) <= 1:
            return item
        else:
            first = item[0]
            left = [i for i in item[1:] if i > first]
            right = [i for i in item[1:] if i <= first]
            return Quick(left, reverse) + [first] + Quick(right, reverse)
    else:
        if len(item) <= 1:
            return item
        else:
            first = item[0]
            left = [i for i in item[1:] if i <= first]
            right = [i for i in item[1:] if i > first]
            return Quick(left, reverse) + [first] + Quick(right, reverse)

def MySort(item, alg=None, reverse=False):

    if alg == 'Bubble':
        Bubble(item, reverse)

    elif alg == 'Insertion':
        Insertion(item, reverse)

    elif alg == 'Quick':
        item = Quick(item, reverse)

    if __name__ == "__main__":

    item1 = [1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 8, 7, 9, 0]
    MySort(item1, alg='Bubble', reverse=True)
    print(item1)

    item2 = [5, 61, 89, 910, 123, 895, 2, 4, 77, 13, 5567, 83, 44]
    MySort(item2, alg='Insertion')
    print(item2)

    item3 = [5, 61, 89, 910, 123, 895, 2, 4, 77, 13, 5567, 83, 44]
    MySort(item3, alg='Quick', reverse=False)
    print(item3)
```

Of course, if I use 'return' to receive the aligned values at the `MySort()` like,

```py
    elif alg == 'Quick':
        item = Quick(item, reverse)
        return item

    item3 = MySort(item3, alg='Quick', reverse=False)
```

it resolve.
But, I want the `item3` list to change using

```
MySort(item3, alg='Quick', reverse= False)
```

rather than

```
item3 = MySort(item3, alg='Quick', reverse=False)
```

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: @tomgalpin aok. Deleting mine too then xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of recursive algorithm are often much easier to deal with when they are pure functions (=> no side effects). Plain simple solution: just wrap the recursive mplementation in a "facade" function that works as expected: (nb: code simplified to avoid repetitions)

```
import operator

# private implementation  
def _quick(item, reverse):
    if len(item) <= 1:
        return item


    if reverse:
        lcomp = operator.gt
        rcomp = operator.le
    else:
        lcomp = operator.le
        rcomp = operator.gt

    first = item[0]
    left = [i for i in item[1:] if lcomp(i, first)]
    right = [i for i in item[1:] if rcomp(i, first)]
    return _quick(left, reverse) + [first] + _quick(right, reverse)

# public facade
def quick(item, reverse):
    # clears `item` and "re-fill" it with the result so
    # we have in-place sorting
    item[:] = _quick(item, reverse)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the list and then add the new elements like this:

```
def mutate(a):
    b = [1,2,3]
    a.clear()
    a += b

a = [4,5,6]
print(a)
mutate(a)
print(a)
```

But I'm not sure why you need to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Please see
[this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051916/how-to-make-a-local-variable-inside-a-function-global)

Your later suggestion of using
`item3 = MySort(item3, alg='Quick', reverse=False)` 
would be the correct way of doing things.