# Can i make dataframe "active" in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I dont know if i'm asking this question right but fell free ask more info if needed.

So i do this dataframe where i read csv file. Then i want to use the file to do another tasks. i want that df to be "active" but it seems like it dont recognise that dataframe outside of button.

```
def on_button_clicked(b):
    df = pd.read_csv(F"./siivous/cleanedfiles/node_{karry.value}.csv")
    with output:
        display (df)
        display(img)
        clear_output(wait=True)
```

So how can i make that dataframe active just click of the button. So excample i wrote print(df) it print that df.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe named `df` is declared inside of a function. If you do this you cannot access to it outside of that function.

I suggest you the check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051916/how-to-make-a-local-variable-inside-a-function-global).

I hope it helped!

Comment: Please avoid “link only” answers. Can you please add a code example. At this point, this answer is more of a comment.

Comment: Hi! I don't think that duplicating the same code is effective. Links are the core of internet. On the other hand, I agree, my answer is more like a comment. Anyway, I think we both agree that the Asker got an answer.